# I have a Toshiba Satellite A205-s6812 and the sound is not working.

Tags: sound, toshiba-satellite

I made sure sound was up all the way. Its not locating the drivers for it, I was wondering if anyone knew what to do to fix this problem, anything is helpfull I'm stumped on it. If anyone has any sugestions or a solution to my poblem I would love to hear it. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

An `lspci` would help... but I'll try.

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-iquik/alsa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Restart.